# Handle multiple service calls to bind to a list in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

Our application has a page that displays the roles and its users as UL lists in a page. 
The users list is populated once we select any roles. Fetching of users is done using a service call below -

```
public getUsers(roles: Any): Users { return service.getUsers(roles).subscribe((users) => this.userList = users; );)
```

The issue is that the roles input for the above function changes dynamically as the role selection in the UI is not disabled while users fetching is still in progress as a result the users list displays incorrect results.

For ex. Role1 and Role2 is selected and the server call is made to fetch the users. While the server call is still in progress i now deselect Role1 but with this i see that the users list is still being populated with the Role1 and Role2 for a few seconds and then the list refreshes with the users of Role2.

This happens because the request is async and the userslist is bound initially with Role1 and Role2 users and later again with Role2 users. Is there any way to stop the on going request to populate the users while we have initiated the second request or any other better approach?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps try calling unsubscribe when deselecting

Comment: You can use Observable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of `Observable`.

When you execute your call to server to get data, you can store it as subscription in variable. And `unsubscribe` from it when you try again:

```
subscription: any;

getUsers(roles: Any): Users {
    if(this.subscription['getUsers']) {
        this.subscription['getUsers'].unsubscribe();
    }

    this.subscription['getUsers'] = service.getUsers(roles).subscribe(
        (users) => this.userList = users; 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can cancel the request using `Observable`. A similar snippet of yours looks like the below. [Plunkr link](http://plnkr.co/edit/m1LBzu?p=preview)

```
    private request:any;
    search() {
      if (this.request) {
         this.request.unsubscribe();
      }
    this.request = this.searchService.search(this.searchField.value)
      .subscribe(
           result => { this.result = result.artists.items; },
           err => { this.errorMessage = err.message; },
           () => { console.log('Completed'); }
      );

   }
```

Comment: Thanks but Mario was first to answer :)